# Inconsistent behavior when retrieving fields in Apex Test Class

Tags: soql, unit-test

I've been experiencing a very strange issue I cannot explain when creating test coverage for my code.

Typically I create all the hierarchy of objects that are involved in the test of a certain functionality. I do this making use of [SmartFactory for Force.com](https://github.com/mbotos/SmartFactory-for-Force.com) (kudos [@mbotos](https://twitter.com/BotosCloud)).

Then at the end of the test class I update the object I need to trigger (in this case is a Trigger on AfterUpdate). Just like this:

```
//Create the record from the object I need to trigger.
WorkOrder__c WO = (WorkOrder__c)SmartFactory.createSObject('WorkOrder__c');
WO.Status__c = 'Open';
insert WO;

//Create a record for a related object
WorkDetail__c WD = (WorkDetail__c)SmartFactory.createSObject('WorkDetail__c');
WD.DateX__c = system.today();
WD.DateY__c = system.today();
WD.LookupZ__c = ID OF A RECORD PREVIOUSLY CREATED
insert WO;
...
//Create some other records
...

WO.Status__c = 'Closed';
update WO;
```

And then finally I proceed to check the values that it should be updating by retrieving the record that should be altered by the trigger, I do it this way:

```
List<Object__c> objUpdated = [SELECT DateA__c,
DateB__c,
LookupC__c 
FROM Object__c 
WHERE Id=:theIdOfARecordInsertedPreviously.Id];

system.assertEquals(objUpdated[0].DateA__c,WD.DateX__c); 
system.assertEquals(objUpdated[0].DateB__c,WD.DateY__c);
system.assertEquals(objUpdated[0].LookupC__c,WD.LookupZ__c);
```

Now, here comes the issue: the SECOND assert rises an error due to objUpdated[0].DateB__c being null.

- I triple-checked that the object is not null.
- The other two asserts are correct.
- No matter what, seems DateB__c is never retrieved (!!!).

Do you have any explanation for this behavior?

Thanks!

Comment: As your test code is straightforward, the problem probably lies in the code that sets the DateB__c value (your trigger - most likely) or the code that sets up the data that your trigger depends on (SmartFactory - less likely its presumably working for many people). I suggest you post your trigger code.

Comment: Hi @KeithC , you are right, the code for the trigger was a bit tangled and I missed to retrieve DateB__c. This gives no error and passed silent until the test. Thank you for the hint!

Comment: This is why unit tests are a good thing.